# Method of dividing geospatial objects into 'buckets' for speed of looking up nearby objects

Tags: gis, shapefile

I need to create an algorithm which allows for objects tagged with a latitude and longitude to be matched with objects in another list which are nearby. To be more specific, the objects in one list are defined by a set of extents which define the shape of the object. The objects in the other list are defined by a series of latitudes and longitudes as they may be miles long and change in direction.

Is there any standard algorithm which will help performance in this kind of situation? I can use a brute force algorithm but given each list contains hundreds of thousands of objects performance will not be adequate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most GIS systems will provide some sort of spatial index, e.g. R-tree, Quad tree, GIST etc. We'd need more detail as to your programming language or program to help more

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks. I'm creating a program myself which is currently in C# using DotSpatial. However I'm right at the beginning so I can switch language easily. The terms you've provided at least give me somewhere to start, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is open source java library available that can serve your purpose.[JSI](https://github.com/aled/jsi) You can take reference from the source code.